# Getting an object to reset to a fixed (x,y) coordinate when a button is pressed in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, animation, uiview

I have a box that fills the screen, and a button. When I press the button, I want the box to move down slowly until it is no longer visible. If the button is pressed during this animation, I want the button to return to its original location, and resume the animation. I have the following code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var backgroundthing: UIView!

@IBAction func button(_ sender: UIButton) {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.0, animations: {self.backgroundthing.frame.origin.y = 0}, completion: nil)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 4.0, animations: {self.backgroundthing.frame.origin.y = 667}, completion: nil)

}
```

If I press the button once, it works "fine", and the box takes the 4 seconds to get off screen. However, if I press the button before the animation is over, the box snaps to a higher position than its original position. For example, if I pressed the button while the box is only half off screen, it would snap to the top, with half of the box above the screen to resume sliding down. The code I am looking for would snap the box to its ORIGINAL position, so no matter how fast or how many times I press the button, it won't go any higher than its original position.

Answer (score 0):

Stop the animation first, reset the block, start a new animation:

```
@IBAction func button(_ sender: UIButton) {
    backgroundthing.layer.removeAllAnimations()
    backgroundthing.frame.origin.y = 0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 4.0) {
        self.backgroundthing.frame.origin.y = 667
    }
}
```